# Java, xml: Почему длинна nodeList не совпадает с тем что есть

Tags: java, xml, dom

Есть такой док:

```
<root>
    1
    <tr>
        a
        <tr>
            aa
        </tr>
        <fls>
            bb
        </fls>
    </tr>
    <fls>
        <tr>
            aaa
        </tr>
        <fls>
            bbb
        </fls>
    </fls>
</root>
```

И такой код:

```
element = doc.getDocumentElement();
NodeList nlist = element.getChildNodes();
System.out.println(nlist.getLength());
```

Почему же я получаю длинну 5
Тогда как по идее должен получать 2
Если `doc.getDocumentElement();` дает мне `root` который содержит в себе 2 дочерних элемента

Comment: Элемент `root` содержит дочерний узел `tr`, узел `fls`, текстовый узел `\n\t1\n\t` и ещё два текстовых узла `\n\t`.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev можно ли обойти лишние узлы или как то сформировать док. что бы без лишних танцев с бубном получать нужную информацию по индексам?

Comment: Смотря, что Вам нужно сделать. Или вы обращаетесь к конкретным узлам по названию/используете XPath или перебираете все и работаете только с нужными проверяя тип узла.